# Twitch tv embedded defaults to autoplay true. Need help turning it to false

Tags: embedding, twitch

I am trying to put multiple twitch tv streams on one page but when i load the page they start right away and that might cause trouble to visitors on my website. I tried in the embedded code to turn autoplay to false but nothing happends. Here is my embedded code.

```
<object style="opacity:1;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620"      id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=optimalbread" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=optimalbread&auto_play=false&start_volume=25" /></object>
```

Can someone please figure out how to set it so that streaming will not start once the page loads. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works I believe twitch fixed it